# In CSS, what does margin do that position property can't do?

Tags: html, css

Can we always use the position property putting relative, absolute values, instead of margin property? Or is there something that states that using the margin is a must? Maybe margin does something that position: absolute/relative/fixed can't do?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-margin-left-px-and-position-relative-left-px).

Answer (score 1):

Margin makes the outer dimensions grow, so it pushes other elements, while positioning doesn't. On top of that, positioning `absolute` or `fixed` takes the element entirely out of de document flow, making it have no influence on the position of other elements, while positioning `relative` only moves relative of where it should be.

```css
div { border:5px solid red }

.margin { margin:5px; }
.relative { position:relative;top:5px;left:5px; }
.absolute { position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px; }
```

```html
<p>Position (absolute):</p>
<div><button class="absolute">bar</button><button class="absolute">foo</button></div>
<p>Margin:</p>
<div><button class="margin">bar</button><button class="margin">foo</button></div>
<p>Position (relative):</p>
<div><button class="relative">bar</button><button class="relative">foo</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The options of position property are used just to decide which elements will affect or not the position of other elements. By default when you don't use the position property every element is in relative state affecting the previews and next element. While margin property is used for making elements stay more left right up down ect or make them stay in the middle and also make them less extensive. In other words they are 2 different properties that collaborate with each other not separately for the same purpose.